# Record an OpenGL animation

Tags: windows, graphics-card, recording, opengl

I need to record an avi from an OpenGL window (not fullscreen).

Do you know a free software for windows XP that can help me ?

Comment: I guess any screen capturing software will do it, just google for it.

Comment: I rely on people that already used such software. Google is good but it doesn't know which one is better among 215,000 possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the trial version of FRAPS if you don't mind a watermark: http://www.fraps.com/download.php

Comment: works like a charm.

Comment: but the saved .avi's are also recorded using a proprietary codec :(

Comment: The FRAPS FAQ suggests using Virtual Dub to convert the output videos to other formats.

Answer (score 1):

yes, Fraps is great if you don't mind the watermark.

Some people spoke me well about Taksi. Is open source. You may want to give it a try :

http://taksi.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 0):

[Camtasia](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.asp) has a free trial.

If you want a hosted solution you can try [Jing](http://www.jing.com)

Comment: We've used Camtasia for screen recording and it is very good, although annoying that saved .avi's are recorded using a proprietary codec that the end-user must download. There's probably ways to convert it though.